# Left Join Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am going to trash Entity Framework 5! I have spent two days to find solution from web but found nothing!

I tried a simple left join from table Artworks and EndValidities with the input IDFondazione as 2620

```
var query = from art in db.Artworks
  join endVal in db.EndValidities.DefaultIfEmpty() 
  on art.ID_Dtsl equals endVal.IDdtsl 
  where art.ID_Cdgs == IDFondazione
  select new SchedaOpera()
  {
    Cdscheda = art.Cdscheda,
    Confirmed = art.FGconfermata,
    DSimmagine = art.DSimmgine,
    Dtsf = art.Dtsf,
    Dtsi = art.Dtsi,
    Dtsl = endVal != null ? endVal.Dtsl : "",
    Iscr = art.Iscr,
    Misa = art.Misa,
    Ldcn = art.Ldcn,
    Ldcs = art.Ldcs,
    Misd = art.Misd,
    Misl = art.Misl,
    Misn = art.Misn,
    Misp = art.Misp,
    Miss = art.Miss,
    Pvcc = art.Pvcc,
    Pvcp = art.Pvcp,
    Sgtt = art.Sgtt
  };
```

The marvellous entity framework continues to produce

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ID_Dtsl] AS [ID_Dtsl], [Extent1].[CDscheda] AS [CDscheda], 
[Extent1].[FGconfermata] AS [FGconfermata], 
[Extent1].[DSimmagine] AS [DSimmagine], 
[Extent1].[DS_DTSF] AS [DS_DTSF], 
[Extent1].[DS_DTSI] AS [DS_DTSI], 
CASE WHEN (cast(1 as bit) <> cast(0 as bit)) THEN [Extent2].[DSdtsl] ELSE N'_' END AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[DS_ISCR] AS [DS_ISCR], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISA] AS [NR_MISA], 
[Extent1].[DS_LDCN] AS [DS_LDCN], 
[Extent1].[DS_LDCS] AS [DS_LDCS], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISD] AS [NR_MISD], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISL] AS [NR_MISL], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISN] AS [NR_MISN], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISP] AS [NR_MISP], 
[Extent1].[NR_MISS] AS [NR_MISS], 
[Extent1].[FGpubblicata] AS [FGpubblicata], 
[Extent1].[DS_PVCC] AS [DS_PVCC], 
[Extent1].[DS_PVCP] AS [DS_PVCP], 
[Extent1].[DS_SGTT] AS [DS_SGTT]
FROM  [dbo].[TPD_OPERE] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TSA_DTSL] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID_Dtsl] = [Extent2].[IDdtsl]
WHERE [Extent1].[CD_CDGS] = '2620'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` in Entity Framework only works on navigation properties. Otherwise you should use [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx), which in comprehensive syntax is achieved by `join` ... `into`. See [this excellent post](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Left-Outer-Join-in-LINQ-to-Entities-%28for-Entity-Framework-4%29.aspx) for more details.

So your query could be (GroupJoin):

```
from art in db.Artworks
join endVal in db.EndValidities on art.ID_Dtsl equals endVal.IDdtsl
into g // can be any name
where art.ID_Cdgs == IDFondazione
...
```

The difference is the statement selects `art` objects and a collection of `endVal` objects per `art` object. So the `Dtsl` property should be a `Select` on `endVal.Dtsl`, producing a collection of `Dtsl` values. The collection can be empty (zero elements), which represents the outer join.

Or, if there is navigation property `Artwork.EndValidities`:

```
from art in db.Artworks
from endVal in art.EndValidities.DefaultIfEmpty() 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

My Demo, tested in linqpad, you can left outer join two tables as below:

```
var resultAcctInfo = (
                from p in Focus_Person
                where String.Compare(p.Login, "yourname", true) == 0 && (p.AcctStatusID == 1 || p.AcctStatusID == 2)
                join an in Focus_SecurityAnswer on p.PersonID equals an.PersonID into G
                //from g in G //You can uncommented this line to check the difference.
                join q in Focus_SecurityQuestion on G.FirstOrDefault().QuestionID equals q.QuestionID into Q  //left join question table
                //from q in Q                   
                select new
                {
                    Person = p,
                    Answer = G.FirstOrDefault(),                        
                    //Question = q,
                });
resultAcctInfo.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from art in db.Artworks
join endValidities in db.EndValidities
on art.ID_Dtsl equals endValidities .IDdtsl into ev
where art.ID_Cdgs == IDFondazione

from endVal in ev.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new SchedaOpera()
     {
          Cdscheda = art.Cdscheda,
          Confirmed = art.FGconfermata,
          DSimmagine = art.DSimmgine,
          Dtsf = art.Dtsf,
          Dtsi = art.Dtsi,
          Dtsl = endVal.Dtsl ?? string.Empty,
          Iscr = art.Iscr,
          Misa = art.Misa,
          Ldcn = art.Ldcn,
          Ldcs = art.Ldcs,
          Misd = art.Misd,
          Misl = art.Misl,
          Misn = art.Misn,
          Misp = art.Misp,
          Miss = art.Miss,
          Pvcc = art.Pvcc,
          Pvcp = art.Pvcp,
          Sgtt = art.Sgtt
     };
```

Comment: mmm code produced exactly as above and my linq is:
from artworks in db.Artworks
join ev in db.EndValidities on artworks.ID_Dtsl equals ev.IDdtsl
into endVal
from ev in endVal.DefaultIfEmpty()
where artworks.ID_Cdgs ==  IDFondazione
select new SchedaOpera() Am I missing something ?

Comment: @velteyn I edited, maybe try last code. It would be easier if you had an `EndValidity` property in Artworks... Can't you ?

Comment: Mmm last code not compiling :(
Mmm and if I put EndValidity property into Artworks how it would change ?

Comment: last last edit compiles now but the result is always a fantastic INNER JOIN [dbo].[TSA_DTSL] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID_Dtsl] = [Extent2].[IDdtsl] :(

Comment: @velteyn well, then give your structure. If an inner join is generated, it might mean that a left join doesn't make sense. Do you have different results with a left or an inner when querying directly the db in SQL ?

Comment: absolutely different ! With the inner I obtain 10 artworks when i do left I obtain 110 artwors, all with DTSL = null but with the other values filled correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have this working code:-

```
  var res = from et in db.entity_test join en in db.entity_new on et.id equals en.id into ps from en in ps.DefaultIfEmpty() select new {Name = et.name,Email=en.email };

    GridView1.DataSource = res;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```